# Working with Temp raster from s3 bucket acquired using s3read_using function

Tags: r, amazon-s3, raster, r-raster

I'm pulling a .tif from an s3 bucket using the aws.s3 R package

```
test_tif <- s3read_using(FUN = raster, object = "test_tif.tif", bucket = "bucketname")
```

This is placing the raster in my Global Environment: test_tif

When i go to perform any sort of raster based operations, i get a repeated error

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
```

no further error codes or warnings

Looking at the structure of the raster, there is a nothing different compared with the same .tif read in from a local directory.

Only difference is one is saved as a temp file.

any ideas on how to work around this.

using s3read_using is a must, as this will eventually be incorporated into a shiny app.

Thanks.

Comment: is there a public bucket with an example file? Or can you make one?

Comment: @RobertHijmans Hi Robert, im glad you saw this, thanks for responding.

Yes, i have created a public bucket and added a public IAM user roll with s3 read access only, but even still id rather not put the access and secret key on stackoverflow - can i send you an email? Thanks.

Comment: sure, please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is see is that `s3read_using` downloads the file (with `save_object`, applies the function with the file as argument, and then deletes the file. That works if the function reads the data into memory. But the `raster` method only reads the metadata from the file; reading the actual values later, as needed.

So if I do

```
r <- s3read_using(FUN = raster, object = "test.tif", bucket = "bucketname")
f <- filename(r)
#"C:\\temp\\RtmpcbsI2z\\file9b846977650.tif"
file.exists(f)
#[1] FALSE
```

The file is gone, and you cannot do anything with RasterLayer `r`.

A work around could be to read all the values immediately. If that is not possible you could also multiply the values with 1. This would have a similar effect, unless files are very large, in which case it would create a (more) permanent temp file.

```
rr <- s3read_using(FUN = function(f) readAll(raster(f)), object = "test.tif", bucket = "bucketname")
# or 
rr <- s3read_using(FUN = function(f) raster(f) * 1, object = "test.tif", bucket = "bucketname")
```

But in that case you might as well use the `save_object` function --- which is what you want to avoid.

Perhaps you can instead use [Cloud Optimized GeoTiff](https://www.cogeo.org/) and access them like this  `"vsicurl/https://mybucket/test.tif"`. You should be able to restrict access to your domain only. Also, the `terra` package might give you better performance than `raster`.